# Different checksum but same archives

Tags: checksum, php-ziparchive

We generated two SHA-256 checksums for two archives (*.zip), which they suppose to have exactly the same contents. However, the two checksums are different.

We checked the files and compare them between the two archives. Their contents are the same, however, the last modified time for some of the files and folders are different.

Also when we are doing Linux 'zip', the 'zip' saves the last modified time information that causes the difference of the checksums. (tried to use zip -X, still generate different checksums)

How do you generate the same checksum in this case?

Comment: As the .zip file contains information metadata like the modified times, the files will be different. Why is this an issue?

Comment: We have a requirement to generate the same checksums if the zip content are the same? Is there a way to create zip without the modified times information?